# PHP get files in directory and list if they are within the last year (filetime)

Tags: php

I need to output the contents of a directory only if the file has been created within the last year.

```
<?php
    $dirpath = "Dir/foo/bar/";
    $files = array();
    $files = glob($dirpath . "*");
    rsort($files);
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $lastYear = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 years"));
    $todayTimeStamp = strtotime($today);
    $beginningTimeTtamp = strtotime($lastYear);
    foreach($files as $item) {
        if(filetime($item)  > $beginningTimeStamp && < $todayTimeStamp) {
            echo "basename($item)";
         }
     }
```

This doesn't return anything - I just want to return $item that is greater than the date a year from today and less than today (not necessary?).

Am I wrong converting the $beginningTimeStamp and $todayTimeStamp to a timestamp to compare filetime? Im not able to convert each $item to its filetime... Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why did you change the accepted answer? I identified all the errors and I was first :)

Comment: Im sorry... didn't know it was a huge thing. I ended up using the other answer bc it was more succinct than what I had

Comment: Not a huge thing, is just frustrating for me to make rep. No worries though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues.  You want to use timestamps.  There's no reason to create timestamps, format them and then convert them back to timestamps.  Also, there's an error in the `if`.  This will work:

```
foreach($files as $item) {
    $mt = filemtime($item)
    if($mt > strtotime('-1 year') && $mt < time()) {
        echo "basename($item)";
     }
 }
```

However, unless something might have a weird time in the future, you just need:

```
foreach($files as $item) {
    if(filemtime($item) > strtotime('-1 year') {
        echo "basename($item)";
     }
 }
```

Comment: filetime is incorrect-> filemtime is correct: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Comment: @ValeriuCiuca edited thanks.  wonder why they were'nt getting _undefined function_?

Comment: When I tested his code, I got undefined function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some typos like `filetime` instead of `filemtime`, etc. I corrected it:

```
$dirpath = "Dir/foo/bar/";
$files = [];
$files = glob($dirpath . "*");
rsort($files);
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$lastYear = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 years"));
$todayTimeStamp = strtotime($today);
$beginningTimeStamp = strtotime($lastYear);
foreach ($files as $item) {
    print "<br>" . filemtime($item) . '<hr>';
    if (filemtime($item) > $beginningTimeStamp && filemtime($item) < $todayTimeStamp) {
        echo "basename($item)";
    }
}
```

I also corrected the if statement and also `$beginningTimeTtamp` had a typo -> `$beginningTimeStamp`